# Why are the last three verses included in the Megillah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, megillat-esther

> וַיָּשֶׂם֩ הַמֶּ֨לֶךְ אחשרש [אֲחַשְׁוֵר֧וֹשׁ ׀] מַ֛ס עַל־הָאָ֖רֶץ וְאִיֵּ֥י הַיָּֽם׃ וְכָל־מַעֲשֵׂ֤ה תָקְפּוֹ֙ וּגְב֣וּרָת֔וֹ וּפָרָשַׁת֙ גְּדֻלַּ֣ת מָרְדֳּכַ֔י אֲשֶׁ֥ר גִּדְּל֖וֹ הַמֶּ֑לֶךְ הֲלוֹא־הֵ֣ם כְּתוּבִ֗ים עַל־סֵ֙פֶר֙ דִּבְרֵ֣י הַיָּמִ֔ים לְמַלְכֵ֖י מָדַ֥י וּפָרָֽס׃ כִּ֣י ׀ מָרְדֳּכַ֣י הַיְּהוּדִ֗י מִשְׁנֶה֙ לַמֶּ֣לֶךְ אֲחַשְׁוֵר֔וֹשׁ וְגָדוֹל֙ לַיְּהוּדִ֔ים וְרָצ֖וּי לְרֹ֣ב אֶחָ֑יו דֹּרֵ֥שׁ טוֹב֙ לְעַמּ֔וֹ וְדֹבֵ֥ר שָׁל֖וֹם לְכָל־זַרְעֽוֹ׃

Thus concludes the Megillah. But what exactly do these verses add? The story was completed back in chapter 9. What do we gain by having chapter 10?

Already checked Torah Temimah, which just quotes the Gemara in Megillah as saying Achashveirosh was called as such for bankrupting the people, as recorded in 10:1. It's more of a drash explanation, though - is there a more pashut pshat one?

To that end I checked my Mikraos Gedolos, where the mefarshim seemed to focus on explaining the words and sentences rather than how it fits into the story as a whole. I could be missing something, or your Mikraos Gedolos might have different mefarshim than mine, so feel free to check my work.

Finally, I checked the Malbim, who asked the question and answers it by saying it's addressing how successful Mordechai was in his new position of power. Although he's addressing passuk aleph, it seems that it would be a more fitting comment to passuk gimmel. Plus, is that not already discussed back in 8:16?

Comment: I think this is a dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55893/759 but frankly that question is somewhat unclear.